# Python loop fix

Tags: python

```
price = float(input("Enter the purchase price:"))
print("Month  Starting Balance  Interest  to Pay  Principal to Pay  Payment  Ending Balance")
#math
start = price * 0.10 - price
monthly = start * .05
interest = start * 0.12 / 12
principal = monthly - interest  
ending = principal - start
for eachPass in range(1 ,24):
    print(eachPass, "%16.2f" % start, "%16.2f" % interest, "%16.2f" % principal, "%13.2f" % monthly, "%16.2f" % ending)
   start = ending
   monthly = start * .05
   interest = start * 0.12 / 12
   principal = monthly - interest  
   ending = principal - start  

 input("press the enter key to exit")
```

I think it has to do with monthly = start * 0.5. Should it be something different?

What the output should be

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Thanks for sharing what output should be, but what output are you getting? What do you mean by "it has to do with"?

Comment: This is not a good question :(, no [mre], lacks almost all details. You have just posted your code and asked to find the problem

Comment: The question is am not getting the right output, and I think it has to do with monthly = start * 0.5, but I am not 100% sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that your prices switch signs every iteration. Positive to negative to positive, etc.

And they start negative, which is a problem.

I think the root of your problem is this:

```
start = price * 0.10 - price
```

sets `price` to be a negative value, since a given positive `price` will always be greater than one-tenth its own value. Maybe change the condition to

```
start = price * 0.90
```

instead?

---

The same issue is present with

```
ending = principal - start
```

in that it should be the other way around,

```
ending = start - principal
```

to keep everything positive. This needs to be done both outside the loop *and* inside the loop.

---

Making those changes and running the code again produced the following output:

```
Month  Starting Balance  Interest  to Pay  Principal to Pay  Payment  Ending Balance
1           180.00             1.80             7.20          9.00           172.80
2           172.80             1.73             6.91          8.64           165.89
3           165.89             1.66             6.64          8.29           159.25
4           159.25             1.59             6.37          7.96           152.88
5           152.88             1.53             6.12          7.64           146.77
6           146.77             1.47             5.87          7.34           140.90
7           140.90             1.41             5.64          7.04           135.26
8           135.26             1.35             5.41          6.76           129.85
9           129.85             1.30             5.19          6.49           124.66
10           124.66             1.25             4.99          6.23           119.67
11           119.67             1.20             4.79          5.98           114.88
12           114.88             1.15             4.60          5.74           110.29
13           110.29             1.10             4.41          5.51           105.88
14           105.88             1.06             4.24          5.29           101.64
15           101.64             1.02             4.07          5.08            97.58
16            97.58             0.98             3.90          4.88            93.67
17            93.67             0.94             3.75          4.68            89.93
18            89.93             0.90             3.60          4.50            86.33
19            86.33             0.86             3.45          4.32            82.88
20            82.88             0.83             3.32          4.14            79.56
21            79.56             0.80             3.18          3.98            76.38
22            76.38             0.76             3.06          3.82            73.32
23            73.32             0.73             2.93          3.67            70.39
```

There's also the issue that your `Payment` column changes values each time instead of remaining fixed at `9.00`, but I'll let you figure that one out on your own (hint: why are you changing `monthly` inside the loop?).

Comment: Thanks for the Help! You Don't understand how much this helps

Comment: @UnknownLearn123 If you have problems with this kind of thing in the future, a useful thing to do is to walk through your own code - pretend _you're_ the computer trying to run it - and write down what each variable is supposed to be at every given step. This helps you figure out when something isn't what it's supposed to be, and why.

Comment: @UnknownLearn123 Try to frame the question in a better way next time, read [ask]. Also if you find an answer useful why not upvote it?  More importantly, if it solves your problem you should accept it (click the tick near the voting buttons)